# REFRENCEERROR: Embed is not defined, What do I do? (Discord.JS)

Tags: discord, discord.js

I was trying to get the reaction roles for my bot and what do I do?

````
if (message.content === '!Sun rr') {
                        const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setTitle('Reaction Roles')
                        .setDescription('React to get your roles!');
                        message.channel.send(embed).then(msg => msg.react(':x:'))```
````

Comment: Show the full code, including info on what `embed` is. This is incomplete as currently written.

Answer (score 0):

You define a variable `exampleEmbed`, then reference `embed`. If you were trying to reference the example embed, your code should look like this:

```js
if (message.content === "!Sun rr") {
  const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Reaction Roles")
    .setDescription("React to get your roles!");
  message.channel.send(exampleEmbed).then((msg) => msg.react(":x:"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined the embed as `exampleEmbed` but you called `embed`. The bot tries to send `embed`, even though it isn't defined. I suggest changing `exampleEmbed` to something like `reactionRoleEmbed` and make sure you change `embed` to the name of the constante.